# why does TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate not work

Tags: three20

My class is like:

```
- (id)init
{
NSLog(@"lalallalalala");
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.title = @"lalal";

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"];
    self.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.title image:image tag:0] autorelease];
    self.variableHeightRows = YES;
    id<TTTableViewDataSource> ds = [MainPageDataSource dataSourceWithItems:nil];
    ds.model = CreateTabModelWithCurrentSettings();
    self.dataSource = ds;

}
return self;
}




- (void)loadView
{
// Create the tableview.

NSLog(@"in MainPageController");

//self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:TTApplicationFrame()] autorelease];
self.view  =[[UIView alloc] init];
self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:TTApplicationFrame() style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];

self.tableView.rowHeight = 80.f;
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];


}



- (id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate {
   return [[[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate alloc] initWithController:self] autorelease];
}
```

CreateDelegate seems not work, no drag & refresh appears. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

@aporat the view controller does extend TTTableViewController and my code changed to:

```
- (id)init
{
NSLog(@"lalallalalala");
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.title = @"app";

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"];
    self.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.title image:image tag:0] autorelease];
    self.variableHeightRows = YES;
    //id<TTTableViewDataSource> ds = [MainPageDataSource dataSourceWithItems:nil];
    //        ds.model = CreateTabModelWithCurrentSettings();
    //      self.dataSource = ds;
    //self.dataSource = [[[MainPageDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];

}
return self;
}


- (void)createModel {
NSLog(@"in createModel");
self.dataSource = [[[MainPageDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];
}

//- (void)loadView
//{
//    // Create the tableview.
//  
//  NSLog(@"in MainPageController");
//  
//    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:TTApplicationFrame()] autorelease];
//  //self.view  =[[UIView alloc] init];
//    self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:TTApplicationFrame()  style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
//  self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
//                       [TTButton buttonWithStyle:@"toolbarButton:" title:@"Toolbar Button"],
//                       [TTButton    buttonWithStyle:@"toolbarRoundButton:" title:@"Round Button"],
//                       nil]; 
//  
//    self.tableView.rowHeight = 80.f;
//    self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
//    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
//  
//
//}
//- (void)viewDidLoad {
//  [super viewDidLoad];
//  
//  self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0;
//}


- (id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate {
return [[[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate alloc] initWithController:self] autorelease];
}
```

Still not appears drag & fresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

- Your view controller has to extend `TTTableViewController`
- Don't override self.view & self.tableView in `loadView`. The `TTTableViewController` load these views for you.
- Create your datasource using the standard method. This function is called automatically if you're using `TTTableViewController`:

  ```
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  - (void)createModel {
      self.dataSource = [[[CurrencyDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];
   }
  ```

What happens if you call this function directly? (This should manually display the drag to refresh header)

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)reload {

  if ([self.tableView.delegate isKindOfClass:[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate class]]) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:ttkDefaultFastTransitionDuration];
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -60.0f);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  }

  [super reload];
}
```

Comment: the view controller does extend TTTableViewController and my code changed to:

Comment: your code looks fine to me. I use TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate in the same way. try the reload function

Comment: what do you mean "reload function"?

Comment: I added a reload function in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks @aporat, added your reload code, not even go into the code. The controller I called is belong to a tab bar, means it is one of tab bar controller's page. Is it possible the problem?

Comment: code in tab bar controller like this:                                            - (void)viewDidLoad {
  [self setTabURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tt://MainPage/(init)",
                                             @"tt://root/2",
            @"tt://root/3",
                                             nil]];
}                                                                                  tt://MainPage/(init) this is the line call the controller in tabbar

Comment: Finally, I found the way: set - (BOOL)isLoaded {return YES;} in my model class then can get the createDelegate work. Thank you @aporat